# Surrogat Key be Created in DW or Stage?

Tags: sql-server, data-warehouse, business-intelligence

Should the surrogate key, for instance customerKey for dimension customer, be created in the stage process and then the all data should be loaded into the dimCustomer or should the customerkey be created automatically in the dimCustomer when you are loading the data to the dimCustomer table?

What is your reflection and experience?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

During loading, usually auto-increment.